# SQL query to get total monthly amount

Tags: mysql, sql, database

| id | name | startDate | endDate | amount | amountPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 03-02-2022 | 08-05-2022 | 1100 | 11.7 |
| 2 | def | 16-02-2022 | 21-05-2022 | 1650 | 17.55 |
| 3 | abc | 08-05-2022 | 08-06-2022 | 500 | 16.12 |

Query to get the following output

**Output**

| Month | TotalAmount |
| --- | --- |
| January | 0 |
| February | 503.1 |
| March | 906.75 |
| April | 877.5 |
| May | 832.91 |
| June | 129.6 |

... so on

Comment: well i'm not sure you can with a sql query, i think you will need to retrieve the data and do the computation in your code

Comment: You need a calendar table here.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a calender using a recursive cte. Then you can sum the daily amount's per month:

```
with recursive cal (d) as (
    select min(startdate) as d from t
    union all 
    select date_add(d, interval 1 day) from cal where d<(select max(enddate) from t)
)
select monthname(cal.d), sum(t.amountperday)
from cal
join t 
    on cal.d between t.startdate and t.enddate
group by monthname(cal.d)

monthname(cal.d)    sum(t.amountperday)
May                 849.03
April               877.50
March               906.75
February            532.35
June                128.96
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b236a150e8f50be1c24d4a179d84d11)

If you want to include "0" months, extend your calendar and use a left join:

```
with recursive cal (d) as (
    select '2022-01-01'
    union all 
    select date_add(d, interval 1 day) from cal where d<'2022-12-31'
)
select monthname(cal.d), coalesce(sum(t.amountperday),0)
from cal
left join t 
    on cal.d between t.startdate and t.enddate
group by monthname(cal.d);

monthname(cal.d)    coalesce(sum(t.amountperday),0)
January     0.00
February    532.35
March       906.75
April       877.50
May         849.03
June        128.96
July        0.00
August      0.00
September   0.00
October     0.00
November    0.00
December    0.00
```

If you are doing such calculations on a regular basis it is probably a good idea to create a calendar table. Additional information such as working holidays etc. can be kept there

Comment: Can we do without recursive as metabase do not accept recursive function?

Comment: create table that act as cal as I mention in my final lines